# change color of listview row

Tags: android, listview

Let me explain in brief.

I have 2 Fragments:

1) Fragment A where user enters some text. here i have also defined 5 buttons each of different colors. From here, the entered text is added to database.

2) Fragment B which has a listview which populates data from that database using customadapter when user click the "Save" button in Fragment A.

Everything is working fine. Data is being saved, loaded into Listview and all. Now remember those 5 buttons with 5 different colors?

**What I Want** is that suppose while adding data in Fragment A, user selected button with color "Orange" suppose, then the row that will be inflated in getView() method of adapter should also have its background orange.
(Something ike Google Keep)

Is that possible?

My Adapter class :

```
public class notesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<notesSingleRow> notes;
Context context;
View convertView;
private static final String TAG = "SampleAdapter";
private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private final Random mRandom;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;
private static final SparseArray<Double> sPositionHeightRatios = new SparseArray<Double>();

public notesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<notesSingleRow> notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
    this.context = context;
    this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mRandom = new Random();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return notes.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return notes.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    final ViewGroup parent) {
    this.convertView = convertView;
    ViewHolder vh;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_single_row, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    vh.txtView = detail(convertView, R.id.notes_grid_text, notes.get(position).getNotes());
    vh.notes_title = detail(convertView, R.id.note_title_added, notes.get(position).getNotesTitle());
    int len = vh.txtView.length();
    if (len == 1 || len ==2){
        vh.txtView.setTextSize(100);
    }
    else if (len == 3){
        vh.txtView.setTextSize(80);
    }
    else if (len == 4){
        vh.txtView.setTextSize(60);
    }
    else if (len ==5){
        vh.txtView.setTextSize(50);
    }
    else if (len == 8){
        vh.txtView.setTextSize(60);
    }

    double positionHeight = getPositionRatio(position);

    vh.txtView.setHeightRatio(positionHeight);
    vh.notes_title.setHeightRatio(positionHeight);
    vh.notes_title.setPaintFlags(vh.notes_title.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

   /* if ((position == 0 || position == 5 || position == 10 || position ==15)) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 112, 67));
    } else if (position == 1 || position == 6 || position == 11 || position ==16) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(29, 233, 182));
    } else if (position == 2 || position == 7 || position == 12 || position ==17) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(121, 134, 203));
    } else if (position == 3 || position == 8 || position == 13 || position ==18) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(205, 220, 57));
    } else if (position == 4 || position == 9 || position == 14 || position ==19) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(224, 64, 251));
    }*/
            return convertView;
}

public void changeColorToOrange() {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 112, 67));
}


static class ViewHolder {
    DynamicHeightTextView txtView, notes_title;
}

private double getPositionRatio(final int position) {
    double ratio = sPositionHeightRatios.get(position, 0.0);

    if (ratio == 0) {
        ratio = getRandomHeightRatio();
        sPositionHeightRatios.append(position, ratio);
        Log.d(TAG, "getPositionRatio:" + position + " ratio:" + ratio);
    }
    return ratio;
}

private double getRandomHeightRatio() {
    return (mRandom.nextDouble() / 2.4) + 0.8;
}
private DynamicHeightTextView detail(View v, int resId, String text) {
    DynamicHeightTextView tv = (DynamicHeightTextView) v.findViewById(resId);
    tv.setText(text);
    return tv;
}
public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}
public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

user add text in this fragment with buttons of different colors:

```
public class add_note_frag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText note, noteTitle;
String user_note, user_note_title;
Button svenote;
ImageView ora, vio, yel, pin;
RelativeLayout rel;
ActionBar ab;
notesAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<notesSingleRow> notes = new ArrayList<notesSingleRow>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_notes_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ab = getActivity().getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    rel = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.notes_rel_lay);
    note = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.note);
    noteTitle = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.note_title);
    svenote = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.savenote);
    adapter = new notesAdapter(getActivity(), notes);
    ora = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.orange);
    vio = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.violet);
    yel = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yellow);
    pin = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pink);
    ora.setOnClickListener(this);
    vio.setOnClickListener(this);
    yel.setOnClickListener(this);
    pin.setOnClickListener(this);
    svenote.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void saveNote() {
    tasks_Database_Operations tasksDatabaseOperations = new tasks_Database_Operations(getActivity());
    user_note = note.getText().toString();
    user_note_title = noteTitle.getText().toString();
    long id1 = tasksDatabaseOperations.insertNote(user_note, user_note_title);
    if (id1 < 0) {
        Log.e("HirakDebug", "add_task_frag failed insertData operation");
    } else {
        Log.d("HirakDebug", "Data sent to be inserted");
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == svenote) {
        saveNote();
        goBackToNoteFrag();
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar)));
    }
    if (v == ora) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)));
        adapter.changeColorToOrange();
    }
    if (v == vio) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.violet));
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.violet)));
    }
    if (v == yel) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow)));
    }
    if (v == pin) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pinkk));
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.pinkk)));
    }
}

public void goBackToNoteFrag() {
    notesListFrag nLF = new notesListFrag();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);
    ft.remove(this);
    ft.replace(R.id.dynamic_content, nLF, "nLF");
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar)));
}
```

Comment: Yes, please post your adapter. We must "play" with the button's onClick and getView

Comment: i updated the question. nignore those commented lines in adapter class. i used them to change background color according to the position of that row. but now i want to change background color according to what user selects

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.

- Pass that selected color to Fragment B on button click.
- Pass that color as an argument to the adapter constructor from fragment B.
- Now you know the color inside the adapter.
- In `getView()` function of the adapter, based on the color, change the background color of the inflated view. using : `view.setBackgroundColor(color);`

See the sample here : https://github.com/vishalvijay/SampleColorListView

Comment: fragment b just has gridview. cant i pass it directly from fragment A?

Comment: i may be wring but what i understand is that data goes this way Fragment A ---> Adapter --inflated in a row--> Fragment B. Once row is inflated, how this is going to work

Comment: It should be: Fragment A ---(with selected color and other info required)---> Fragment B (fetch data from db) ---> Adapter to populate the data to grid view

Comment: oh.. thnk u.. i will try with your method

Comment: can u plz help me with ur solution. i mean few line of codes on how to exactly implement that in my case will be thankful

Comment: awesome. +1 for ur efforts. also check Mukesh Rana's answer. its simple, but it did the job. Thank you very much. ur sample changes the color of every row. my requirement was to change the color of the row that is being added . however, ur concept is very much helpful in many other cases. thank u again

Answer (score 1):

As far as I think all you have to do is to save color hex code also in your database alongwith your text. It is more simple and scaleable. when you fetch text from database, you should also fetch the color in the same ArrayList of custom objects and then in getView method of your adapter, just apply the corresponding Hex color code to your convertView.